# Client Libraries for Google Maps vs API Client Library

Tags: python, google-maps

What's the difference between the python version of [Client Libraries for Google Maps Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library) and [API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/)?

I thought the latter is supposed to be the comprehensive library to connect to all Google products; but I guess not?